# selenium doesn't want the website to get to the 3rd page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webscarab

Whenever I want selenium to press enter for me, it doesn't want to, get to the next page.
Is something wrong with the code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
PATH = "C:\Pro\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://insurify.com")
try:
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "zipcodeInput"))
    )
    search.send_keys('34997')
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead-input > div > span > input:nth-child(2)"))
    )
    element1.send_keys("2016")
    element1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(30)
    element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead-input > div > span.twitter-typeahead > input:nth-child(2)"))
    )
    element2.send_keys('BMW')
    element2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    element3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead-input > div > span.twitter-typeahead > input:nth-child(2)"))
    )
    element3.send_keys('4-Series')
    element3.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    element4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead-input > div > span.twitter-typeahead > input:nth-child(2)"))
    )
    element4.send_keys('428i')
    element4.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(50)


except:
    driver.quit
```

Also there's a picture for the last code execution of the code.

[image]

Comment: it is not clear what is the problem? the code works fine

Comment: The problem is, that it doesn't want to hit enter with the last word 428i, to enter the 3rd page

Comment: Try using the method i showed you in the other question

Comment: Can you please tag it, I don't seem to find it.

Comment: it seems like you deleted it, i cannot find it, you asked how to select the year 2016 from the drop down menu, do you remember?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to delete it, 

BUT THANKS SO MUCH, it worked perfectly, you are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `driver.implicitly_wait(30)` right after the definition of `driver`, we can get rid of all the commands `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((...)))`. Moreover, with a proper use of `find_element()` and `click()` we can replace the blocks of code such as

```
element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead-input > div > span > input:nth-child(2)")))
element1.send_keys("2016")
element1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

with a one line command. The final code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(your_chromedriver_path))

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://insurify.com")

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#zipcodeInput').send_keys('34997')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="View my quotes"]').click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text() = "2016"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[text()="BMW"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="4-Series"]').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text() = "428i"]').click()
```